# Wordpress: Mobile view does not work properly | Make website mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, woothemes

I've got an online shop, based on wordpress, with the theme "Mystile".

I created many pages with own HTML and CSS codes and they're looking very good on the computer, in every browser and display size.
But the automatic mobile view of the theme is displaying all the self coded stuff terribly.

For example:
I'd wanted to separte some pictures on the home page, which are placed under each other, with a simple line.
So I used a HTML code like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: 10px;">___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</div>
```

The line has exactly the right length that the separation looks good.
But of course the width of the mobile view of the website is much less than the desktop view, so this separation line looks terrible on the smartphone.

On other themes mobile view you can defenitely notice a defined width of the view, so my separation line get displayed only that long that it fits in the mobile view.
In my current theme this is not the case, it seems that the mobile view is just a kind of convertion of the whole website and not a clearly defined box where the content gets displayed.

I really stuck here because the website is finished coded and it looks very good on the computer, on any display size ect.
Only the mobile view is the problem.

What can and should I do?

Comment: You should use `<hr />` instead of all that underscores

Comment: Is that a div full of underscores? Try using `<hr/>` instead.

Comment: @Zander, you shouldn't replace your original question with a new one. All given answers are now irrelevant although they solved your problem. I recommend to undo your edit and ask your new question in a new topic. Accepting the answer that solved your problem will help other users as well.

Comment: Ok, I understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a div with underscores you could use the `<hr/>` tag.

In the following example you can resize a container and the line will always be 100% width. You could even use CSS to style the line.

```css
div {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 24px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
  width: 200px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
  <hr/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200">
</div>
```